# How to add the previous element to current jQuery selection?

Tags: jquery

I need to select an element along with its previous sibling.

Relevant HTML:

```
<label></label>
<div id="atc-codes-label"></div>
```

Tried this but it didn't work:

```
$('#search-form #atc-codes-label').add($(this).prev('label'));
```

I'm quite sure that the solution is very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

```
$('#search-form #atc-codes-label').prev().addBack()
```

Since id will be unique you can shorten it to

```
$('#atc-codes-label').prev().addBack()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var atc =$('#atc-codes-label');
atc.add(atc.prev('label'));
```